# Копирование LIst JAVA

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        Integer[] b = new Integer[]{5, 6, 7, 8};
        Integer[] c = new Integer[]{9, 10, 11, 12};
        Integer[] d = new Integer[]{13, 14, 15, 16};
        ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);
        list.add(d);
        ArrayList<Integer[]> list2 = (ArrayList<Integer[]>) list.clone();


        System.out.println("Исходная матрица: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(list.get(i)[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        Max max_elem = new Max();
        int max = max_elem.check_max_element(list);
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент: " + max);

        Min min_elem = new Min();
        int min = min_elem.check_min_element(list);
        System.out.println("Минимальный элемент: " + min);

        System.out.println("Замена матрицы 1: ");
        Zamena1 zamena1 = new Zamena1();
        zamena1.zamena1(list, max);

        System.out.println("Матрица без замены 1: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(list2.get(i)[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно скопировать значение матрицы с list в list2, но ArrayList<Integer[]> list2 = (ArrayList<Integer[]>) list.clone(); содержит ссылку на list, поэтому при изменение list2, будет меняться list.
Что будет оптимально осуществить, чтобы list2 содержал значения list, но не ссылался на него? Метод zamena1 меняет нечетные числа на максимальный элемент в матрице.

**Мой некорректный вывод:**

Исходная матрица:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
Максимальный элемент: 16
Минимальный элемент: 1
Замена матрицы 1:
16 2 16 4
16 6 16 8
16 10 16 12
16 14 16 16
Матрица без замены 1:
16 2 16 4
16 6 16 8
16 10 16 12
16 14 16 16
Там где **Матрица без замены 1:** хочу ожидать вывод:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16

Comment: могу предложить создать новый список `list2`, а потом заполнить его через `list.forEach ((row)->list2.add(row.clone()));`

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае `list.clone()` выполняет поверхностное (*shallow*) копирование, то есть список-копия содержит ссылки на те же массивы, что и оригинальный список `list`.

Для глубокого копирования следует скопировать все элементы списка `list` в новый список, например, при помощи Stream API и метода `clone` для каждого элемента-массива:

```java
List<Integer[]> list2 = list.stream() // Stream<Integer[]>
    .map(Integer[]::clone)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Аналогично, можно использовать метод `Arrays.copyOf`:

```java
List<Integer[]> list2 = list.stream() // Stream<Integer[]>
    .map(arr -> Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Кроме того, в *данном* случае можно реализовать метод, генерирующий исходный список, и тогда вместо копирования достаточно будет вызвать данный метод дважды с одними и теми же аргументами:

```java
private static List<Integer[]> generate(int from, int to, int rows) {
    int cols = (to - from + 1) / rows;
    return IntStream.range(0, rows)
        .mapToObj(r -> IntStream.range(from + cols * r, from + cols * (r + 1))
            .boxed()
            .toArray(Integer[]::new)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// ...
List<Integer[]> list = generate(1, 16, 4);
List<Integer[]> list2 = generate(1, 16, 4);
```